# Save current file path to variable not working

Tags: php, variables, dir

I've a project, with various subdirs that make use of a functions.php file located in the project root folder

```
include "../functions.php";
```

The thing is that I need to save the current subdir path so on reloading the page, it will redirect me to the folder I was before, and not the root folder.

```
header('Location: '.$currFolder.'index.php');
```

To do so, I (try to) store it to a variable by calling a function in each subdir index.php file

```
$currFolder = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); // returns "/root/subdir"
```

But for some reason, variable stays empty, so the header keeps redirecting me to root... What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to save your value in the session or in a cookie. Try this:

```
$_SESSION['currFolder'] = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

Then you can retrieve it with:

```
$currFolder = $_SESSION['currFolder'];
```

Of course make sure you have called session_start() before trying to use the $_SESSION variable.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply! Could you explain me why my code isn't working, please?

Comment: @Dane411, if you are setting a variable before redirecting with the Location header it will lose all those previous settings. The Location header causes the new page to be completely reloaded, not included. So any variables you set on a previous page are gone after the redirect.

Comment: Just in threads topic, the fact to have a parent folder script is to share it, so changes must be done only once, and thus avoid redundancy. But the assignment only works if I add it to subdirs index.php, as if I add it to the included file, it gets top folder instead (the one that contains this script)... Is there any way to achieve it, so that assignment can be set in the included file, like in a function or something?